# AndroidPlot positioning labels

Tags: android, androidplot

I have problem with chart on Android. I draw it with AndroidPlot.
My problem is as follows.
Labels of points on the edges of the graph is not drawn in full. Part of the label is drawn on a chart area as in the screenshot below (points 2 and 3).
In addition, should draw one more label on the bottom (point 1).

Screen http://postimg.org/image/d79e91q2p/

Code to prepare chart before draw:

```
Widget gw = plot.getGraphWidget();
    plot.setGridPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    plot.getDomainLabelWidget().setMarginBottom(50);
    SizeMetrics sm = new SizeMetrics(0, SizeLayoutType.FILL, 0,
            SizeLayoutType.FILL);
    gw.setSize(sm);
    LayoutManager lm = plot.getLayoutManager();
    gw.position(0, XLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_LEFT, 0,
            YLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_TOP);

    // set colors
    plot.getBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
    plot.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    plot.setBorderStyle(BorderStyle.NONE, null, null);
    gw.getBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
    plot.getGraphWidget().getGridBackgroundPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
    plot.getGraphWidget().getDomainLabelPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);
    plot.getGraphWidget().getRangeLabelPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);

    // labels orientation
    plot.getGraphWidget().setDomainLabelOrientation(-90);
    // remove legend
    plot.getLayoutManager().remove(plot.getLegendWidget());

    // set min and max for Y
    plot.setRangeBoundaries(min, max, BoundaryMode.FIXED);
    // set step for Y
    plot.setRangeStep(XYStepMode.INCREMENT_BY_VAL, 20);
```

I think is something with margins or padding.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to add some padding to your plot's graph area to give enough drawable space for those labels.  Exactly how much padding you need depends on the max number of digits you want to display but to start, try adding these lines to your plot's xml:

```
androidPlot.graphWidget.gridPaddingLeft="6dp"
androidPlot.graphWidget.gridPaddingRight="6dp"
```

Nick